# How would the prison system react to an (Unprovable) immortal inmate?

Tags: society, immortality, prison

The year is 1922, in the (real life) United States. For a slew of *particularly* nasty criminal offences, a young man has been sentenced to 100 years in prison, without parole.

Fast forward 100 years, to the end of his sentence, and this man is set to be released. To the puzzlement of the guards, this long-term inmate has not changed in the slightest. He is the same sour-faced young man imprisoned a century ago, in spite of everything which suggests this should be impossible.

Unbeknownst to all but the man, he is immortal, having not aged a day since the reign of Alexander the Great. There are no scientific indicators of this; his blood tests, urine tests, and every other possible tests are identical to any other humans. There are, in short, no scientific ways of proving he is immortal. He also refuses to admit he is immortal, (sarcastically) claiming his continued youthfulness is the result of "good nutrition". Considering the length of time he has existed, 100 years is a short time to wait.

Furthermore, he has no administrative papers to signify his identity, having entered the country illegally, and has kept an exceedingly low profile for the majority of his long, long life, making the discovery of any reference to him from past historical eras next to impossible(Not to mention that anyone who ever met him before his imprisonment is most likely dead). To make a long story short, they know next to nothing about him, and cannot really gain any more information.

My question is thus; if an offender managed to survive, unchanged, to the end of a century-long sentence with no biological, historical or administrative evidence to suggest his being any different, always claiming that he was simply an extremely healthy 120 year old man, would the criminal justice system be obliged to set him free, in spite of his blatant, if unproveable, affront to all the laws of biology?

Comment: What is the government like? Are they a "fair" government, or a totalitarian government that just gives out sentences here and there? Knowing the justice systems and courts of your world is a very important detail.

Comment: This seems like something that is entirely about the decisions of an organization within your already built world. Such a question isn't permitted on this site since it isn't about building the world but writing how events within the world will transpire.

Comment: The immortal fellow might have more pressing problems than the state: "*Hey elderly mob boss, the mook in cell 23 has the secret to eternal youth. Should we 'invite' him for a chat?*"

Comment: (a) The prison system would have discovered something was wrong after the first decade (people age distinctly in just years, not decades or centuries). If you write your story to avoid this, then your Q is too story-based (because the reaction can be anything you want). (b) In the U.S., by the 1950s the guy would likely have been dissected by the military. (c) If the guy's been around since Alexander the Great, he either has a LOT of prison experience (knows how to hide his aging in prison) or his capture is unbelievable. Food for thought.

Answer (score 4):

Bureaucracy can be really dumb sometimes, in the sense that it doesn't ask questions beyond what are the documented evidence and procedures. E.g. if the papers say John Doe has a debt of 0.01 $ with the tax office, he will be requested to pay it, even though carrying out the entire procedure will cost way more than that.

In this case, if the papers say "keep him in jail 100 years" and the procedure at the end of the sentenced time is to set the prisoner free, so it will be done. Questions on how can that be possible are scientific questions, and bureaucrats are not paid to be curious.

Maybe if the word of this strange fellow reaches the hear of some scientist this could trigger some investigation, but not in the justice system.

Comment: I would expect that word to reach someone long before the sentence is up. Even 30 or 40 years unchanged would be enough for some guard to comment and as time marches on more of them are going to do so. Wouldn't surprise me at all if some higher government official comes by and sends him somewhere much worse than a regular prison.